# Limit the Excerpt field in WP-Admin in words

Tags: php, javascript, excerpt, limit, customization

Is it possible to limit the Excerpt field on the post page in words? Note that I am aware that it's possible to echo the excerpt and limit it in words, but I want the field itself to limit the amount of words, similar to how character limits on text-areas work.

**Is such thing possible**? Maybe a Javascript solution? Maybe something similar to what [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/limit-bio/) does to the character bio field (although its limitation is based on amount of characters).

The reason of this is that I run a multiple author platform where users often make the mistake to exceed the word limit that is being printed in the list of posts.

Comment: Check [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/9285/12615), [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/69204/12615) and [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/70033/12615). And reminding that it is ok to answer your own Q :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like [jQuery Simply Countable plugin](https://github.com/aaronrussell/jquery-simply-countable/) and attach it to excerpt input.

```
Limit_Excerpt_Words::on_load();

class Limit_Excerpt_Words {

    static function on_load() {

        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( __CLASS__, 'admin_enqueue_scripts' ) );

    }

    static function admin_enqueue_scripts() {

        global $hook_suffix;

        if ( 'post.php' == $hook_suffix || 'post-new.php' == $hook_suffix ) {

            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-simply-countable', plugins_url( '/jquery.simplyCountable.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), '0.4.2', true );

            add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', array( __CLASS__, 'admin_print_footer_scripts' ) );
        }
    }

    static function admin_print_footer_scripts() {

        ?>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
      jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

          $('#excerpt').simplyCountable({
              countType:'words', maxCount:5, strictMax:true
          });

      });
  </script>

  <span id="counter" style="display:none;"></span><!-- needs counter to work -->
    <?php
    }
}
```

PS there is also `word-count.js` in WP core, but I can't make sense if it's as easy to use for blocking stuff.

Comment: Can you please provide me more information about exactly how I attach it to the excerpt input. I will admit that I am a bit confused about how to go about this. Thank you for the respond regardless.

Comment: @Amanda Duke example code in answer already does that (`$('#excerpt')...` part).

Comment: Yes I found that, I was referring to how I add this example code to my site? Add it to functions.php?

Comment: @Amanda Duke this is coded like a basic plugin and the only think that will differ depending on where you put it is URL to script file. "Where code goes" is hard question to answer because there are umpteenth places to put it and _you_ are supposed to decide that, depending on your needs and setup you have.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, my account was temp suspended. Back to the subject, yes I fully understand what you mean about how to implement the code, this was not an issue. I was asking the question as I tried it already as a plugin (added full path to the js file) and nothing happened... therefore I suspected that the code may need to be added somewhere else. Nonetheless, have you tested this code? Maybe there is a typo somewhere that is preventing it from functioning? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Amanda Duke yep, the code was tested and working in my local test environment.

Comment: Can you please confirm how it functions for you? Once you have typed more than the limited amount of words, does it stop you from typing more characters live? Or does it cut down the words upon update of post? Also, is there any chance that you can double check the code that you have pasted here as I seriously cannot make this work, I just tested it on a fresh Wordpress install...

Comment: @Amanda Duke ah, noticed the probable cause - I only bothered to check for `post.php` to detect editor editor, but _new_ posts are on `post-new.php`.

Comment: can you please update your answer accordingly and I will  give the code a shot.

Comment: Works perfectly! This is a great answer. Thank you Rarst.

Comment: Used it with my meta box, worked great but I have been using latest version of jquery with my installation and it still didn't recognize '$(function(){ });', I had to use document.ready()